# Send mail via EWS: Schema validation: invalid child element 'Body'

Tags: c++, email, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send an e-mail from within a C++ application via a Microsoft Exchange 2010 server. For this, I use the EWS protocol using the library [ews-cpp](https://github.com/otris/ews-cpp).

The following trivial example, based on the one from https://github.com/otris/ews-cpp/blob/master/examples/send_message.cpp, is failing (mail addresses and credentials stripped from my actual code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ews/ews.hpp>

struct {
    std::string domain = "mailserver";
    std::string username = "...";
    std::string password = "...";
    std::string server_uri = "https://mailserver/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
} env;

int main()
{
    ews::set_up();

    try
    {
        auto service = ews::service(env.server_uri, env.domain, env.username,
                                    env.password);
        service.set_request_server_version(ews::server_version::exchange_2010_sp2);

        auto message = ews::message();

        message.set_subject("Test mail from outer space");
        std::vector<ews::mailbox> recipients;

        recipients.push_back(ews::mailbox("..."));
        message.set_to_recipients(recipients);

        auto text = ews::body("This is a test.");
        message.set_body(text);

        service.create_item(message,
                            ews::message_disposition::send_and_save_copy);
    }
    catch (ews::schema_validation_error& exc)
    {
        std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << exc.violation() << std::endl;
    }

    ews::tear_down();
    return 0;
}
```

The raw SOAP request is as follows (indentation added by me):

```xml
<m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
  <m:Items>
    <t:Message>
      <t:Subject>Test mail from outer space</t:Subject>
      <t:ToRecipients>
        <t:Mailbox>
          <t:EmailAddress>...</t:EmailAddress>
        </t:Mailbox>
      </t:ToRecipients>
      <t:Body BodyType="Text">This is a test.</t:Body>
    </t:Message>
  </m:Items>
</m:CreateItem>
```

The function `create_item` throws an `ews::schema_validation_error` which is caught in the above code, printing:

```
The request failed schema validation
The element 'Message' in namespace ‘http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types’ has invalid child element 'Body' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'CcRecipients, BccRecipients, IsReadReceiptRequested, IsDeliveryReceiptRequested, ConversationIndex, ConversationTopic, From, InternetMessageId, IsRead, IsResponseRequested, References, ReplyTo, ReceivedBy, ReceivedRepresenting' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.
```

In other words, EWS doesn't expect `<t:Body>` within `<t:Message>`.

So, when leaving out that element in the SOAP request (comment out `message.set_body(text)`), the mail is sent smoothly. However, a mail without a body doesn't make much sense, does it?

I thought that the problem might be the fact that `ews-cpp` was written for Exchange 2013 (and that the schema changed between 2010 and 2013 in this regard). So I digged into the schema, which each Exchange server serves at `/ews/types.xsd`, to see if the schema allows such a child element.

In the schema definition file, I found the definition of the type `MessageType` (which is the type of the `Message` element we are talking about):

```xml
<xs:complexType name="MessageType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="t:ItemType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Sender" minOccurs="0" type="t:SingleRecipientType"/>
        <xs:element name="ToRecipients" type="t:ArrayOfRecipientsType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="CcRecipients" type="t:ArrayOfRecipientsType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="BccRecipients" type="t:ArrayOfRecipientsType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="IsReadReceiptRequested" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="IsDeliveryReceiptRequested" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="ConversationIndex" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="ConversationTopic" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="From" type="t:SingleRecipientType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="InternetMessageId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="IsRead" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="IsResponseRequested" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="References" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="ReplyTo" type="t:ArrayOfRecipientsType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="ReceivedBy" type="t:SingleRecipientType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="ReceivedRepresenting" type="t:SingleRecipientType" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, there is no `Body` child element, but `MessageType` is based on `ItemType`, which is defined as follows (excerpt):

```xml
<xs:complexType name="ItemType">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="MimeContent" type="t:MimeContentType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="ItemId" type="t:ItemIdType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="ParentFolderId" type="t:FolderIdType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="ItemClass" type="t:ItemClassType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="Subject" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="Sensitivity" type="t:SensitivityChoicesType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="Body" type="t:BodyType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="Attachments" type="t:NonEmptyArrayOfAttachmentsType" minOccurs="0"/>
    [...]
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, it accepts the `Body` element as a child.

Note that the `Subject` element is also defined in the `ItemType` and not in `MessageType`, and that is accepted by EWS in the above code snippet.

What might be the cause of this strange validation failure?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself:

For the element `Message`, which is based on `Item` according to the schema definition, EWS first expects all child elements for `Item`, followed by the `Message`-specific child elements.

This sounds very insane (to me), but swapping `<t:ToRecipients>` and `<t:Body>` in the `<t:Message>` element indeed solved the problem.

I did this by swapping the two corresponding setters in my code:

```
    auto message = ews::message();


    // First, set properties of the general "item":

    message.set_subject("Test mail from outer space");

    auto text = ews::body("This is a test.");
    message.set_body(text);


    // Then, set properties of the concrete "message":

    std::vector<ews::mailbox> recipients;
    recipients.push_back(ews::mailbox("..."));
    message.set_to_recipients(recipients);
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug in `ews-cpp`, in EWS / Exchange server, or in the EWS schema definition.